# How to use Wordpress Multisite with multiple TLDs

Tags: wordpress, multisite, tld

I'm trying to setup a Wordpress Multisite installation (it's basically for two countries AU and NZ) that shows different content depending on the URL (.com.au and .co.nz). I've setup the installation and it seems that by default Wordpress only allows a sub-domain or a sub-directory setup and not a full top-level-domain sub-site.
Is there a way around this at all? I would think that this sort of setup is pretty standard. Am I missing something obvious or would I need some sort of plugin etc. to achieve this?

Comment: **Plugin-less Answer:** [How to use Wordpress Multisite With Different Domain Names?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/251146/9579) on WordPress Development.

Answer (score -1):

Vanilla WP Multisite only support sub-domain and sub-directories but thanks to the awesome developers, you can use the plugin called [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/#installation) to achieve what you've asked for.

There's a bit of setting up and installation process and it's all laid out in the #installation section of the plugin page.

Hope this helped and do comment if you've any issues.